# Migration options for off topic questrions

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, migration

It is rare that I vote to close a question, but [this one](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19517/what-are-some-promising-databases-coming-out-and-being-researched) was clearly off-topic, so I did.

As part of the close process I was given the option to recommend it for migration, but the only available destination was here, in meta.

I have seen quite a few questions here which, like that one, seem like good candidates for [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), couldn’t we recommend migration there when voting to close?

Comment: Well, apparently this site [graduated in September 2015](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2298/congratulations-software-recommendations-is-graduating), so shouldn't we be getting reasonable migration options?

Comment: It seems not :-(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a beta site, we can't migrate to other sites. Once we graduate, we'll have the option of migrating to other sites and have other sites migrate to us.

Note that moderators can migrate to any site on the network, just not normal users. If you see something that *clearly* belongs somewhere else, and the author hasn't already cross-posted it, flag it.

Comment: Full ack :) And just to leave a marker for "then": We should clearly consider having SU in the migration list (for those "how to" questions). Maybe it would also be a nice idea to have one Meta-Q collecting "migration candidates", grouped by their target sites – so when the day comes, we see what should be in "our list" then?

Comment: Maybe @Izzy, but it could be a pain to update for the next year or however long it takes us to graduate.

Comment: I'm open for alternatives. Never having been a mod, I don't know whether you have a stats tool at least for those Qs that *were* migrated? I wouldn't wonder if there was some "query tool" for that. Then we had at least a basic part covered. (and yes, I know we're still in Beta – but I also know that migrations are already taking place in both directions ;)

Comment: @Izzy We do, and [you do too](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/away) as a 2k user. We could probably use that for the stats when we graduate, yes. I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Ah, I *knew* there was something. My bad not having checked the "Tools" section lately... Thanks, that should be a good guide then. Even better with a customized query a la `SELECT site, count(*) AS questions … GROUP BY site ORDER BY questions DESC`, then pick the first (few) entry/entries :) // BTW: on a quick glance, SU on top as expected. OpenData makes a good candidate as well, also not unexpected …

Comment: @Izzy Even if we graduated today, there's no site that would be anywhere close to a migration candidate. It's extremely rare for us to get questions that can be migrated to another site. We don't have many how-to questions, let alone ones worth migrating.

Comment: Admitted, @Gilles: Checking the stats Undo linked, it's one post per month migrated (on average). Not really something to make a lot of fuzz about – as long as it's fine for you mods that in such cases we just flag the Q "other" and put the corresponding flag-comment.