# Can we have migration sites in the off-topic close reasons - and which?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, migration

Since [graduation](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2298/congratulations-software-recommendations-is-graduating) we should be able to have migration targets ([not available when the site was still beta](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1197/migration-options-for-off-topic-questrions)).

I suggest [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) and [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), those seem to be the most common candidates (in that order).
We currently have only this meta.

I must confess I have no idea what is required to set up migration targets

**Edited to give this question some meat to the bone**:
Note that I have read the answers so far and this actually backs them up.
This is my close vote history over the past 180 days, and the triage I would apply:

Questions that would be good enough to migrate to SU (although some may be duplicates there):

- (21 jan 2016) https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/28204/using-a-printer-through-rj-47-connected-computer
- (20 jan 2016) https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/28170/how-do-i-restore-files-in-windows-8
- (19 jan 2016) [How do I open .FILE extensions?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/28151/how-do-i-open-file-extensions)
- (15 Oct 2015) [Install windows 7 on a VM running in Windows 7](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/25729/install-windows-7-on-a-vm-running-in-windows-7)
- (19 Aug 2015) [Dead links in Onenote](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/23152/dead-links-in-onenote)

Questions that would **not** be good enough to migrate to SU:

- (3 jan 2016) [What are your tips on making double sided printable flashcards with onenote or other software?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/27709/what-are-your-tips-on-making-double-sided-printable-flashcards-with-onenote-or-o)

Questions that would be good enough to migrate to SO (or maybe Programmers) (although some may be duplicates there):

- (17 Jul 2015) [Semantic validation of xsd schemata](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/21527/semantic-validation-of-xsd-schemata)

Questions that would **not** be good enough to migrate to SO:

- (26 Oct 2015) https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/25996/multi-class-classification-in-r
- (31 Aug 2015) [Dealing with malicious js in html5 banners](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/23442/dealing-with-malicious-js-in-html5-banners)
- (23 Aug 2015) [terminology for the selection mechanism built in web-browsers](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/23263/terminology-for-the-selection-mechanism-built-in-web-browsers)
- (11 Aug 2015) [How can I develop a web app that's as good as a native mobile app?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/22912/how-can-i-develop-a-web-app-thats-as-good-as-a-native-mobile-app)
- (31 Jul 2015) [Should I switch to AngularJS? (Angular vs Jquery)](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/21617/should-i-switch-to-angularjs-angular-vs-jquery)

Comment: Right on first sight, I'd agree. Just would like more opinions on that. Do you think it might make sense putting one suggested site per answer, so we can discuss them separately? I e.g. saw multiple questions I thought belong to SU (so I'd upvote that), but am not sure about SO.

Answer (score 5):

Our [migration statistics](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats) (link requires 2k rep) for the past 3 months are: 3 questions migrated.

Even accounting for the fact that some questions would have been migrated if there had been a way to do it without involving mods (most questions manage to get closed without mod involvement), that's *way* too small to warrant creating migration paths.

In my experience (as a former moderator), this site gets very very few questions that could be answered elsewhere. Usually, when a question is asked here and would be on-topic on SO or SU, it's lacking a lot of information to be answerable. There's a strong correlation between posting on a site without reading what it's about and not including enough information in the question.

Migrating good but off-topic questions is positive but migrating questions that should be closed on the target site is a very bad experience for everyone. When the question gets closed on the target site, it's thrown back to the original site (which had already decided that it was off-topic), so even if the question is edited to add the missing information, the asker still needs to re-ask on the correct site. We've had this problem often in the opposite direction, with software recommendation questions that were migrated to us in an unanswerable state.

I don't foresee any migration paths from this site for a long time.

Comment: Very good points (+1) – and I especially want to highlight the "very bad experience" mentioned in the "large paragraph". We just experience that one over at Android.SE, getting dropped in things just because they mention the word "Android" – but either being completely off-topic, or lacking necessary details. So I agree to approach that with caution: for now, if you think something should be migrated, mark it for us mods and let us check. But keep the ball low, will you? ;)